# How create text with Linear Gradient?

Tags: c++, winapi

Create LinearGradientBrush

```
LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush(
        Point(0, 10),
        Point(200, 10),
        Color(255, 255, 0, 0),   
        Color(255, 0, 0, 255)
);
```

How I can draw text using this gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearGradientBrush *linGrBrush=new LinearGradientBrush(
        Point(0, 10),
        Point(200, 10),
        Color(255, 255, 0, 0),   
        Color(255, 0, 0, 255));

    Graphics *graphics=new Graphics(hdc);
     PointF drawPoint = PointF(150.0F,150.0F);
     SolidBrush* myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color::Black);
    graphics->DrawString(L"Test text",strlen("Test text"),fn,drawPoint,linGrBrush);
```